# Jetpack Compose TextField/OutlinedTextField Strange Behavior in Some Devices With Lower Versions

Tags: android, kotlin, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

After using some **special characters** in Jetpack compose Textfield component. It makes some different behaviours. For example:

```
When I write xyz@a. It is OK, but after clicking "b". Text turns as "xyz@ a" (expected: xyz@ab).


When I write xyz@p. It is OK, but after clicking "r". Text turns as "xyz@rp" (expected: xyz@pr).


When I write xyz@a. It is OK, but after remove, text turns as "xyza" (expected: xyz@).
```

These types of error occurs everytime after clicking the special characters. Only if I set keyboard type as `KeyboardType.Password` it works correctly. After look logs I see that those weird results are got as parameter of `onValueChange` function.

Some tested devices:

No errors on devices that have Android version equals or higher than 9.0 that I tested.

No errors on any version/device at Android Emulator that I tested.

I confront this error Samsung Note 3 (Android Version: 5.0) and Samsung Grand Prime (Android Version: 6.0).

Any idea?

Comment: I suggest you [report it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) on the issue tracker

Comment: I opened https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208855078. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You should use rememberSaveable rather than remember

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).